# Defining environments calling other environments (bug in 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.21)

Tags: environments, latex-base

A strange error has suddenly appeared after I upgraded Debian, resulting in an update of texlive.  Does anyone know the source of this error?  How to fix it?  I have used similar constructs for more than twenty years, and they have appeared safe and sound until now. I really don't want to rewire old class files if I can avoid it.  My searches turn up false hits only.  TIA

(EDIT) The original minimal example was solved and explained by David Carlisle below. The following example is less trivial.

```
% cat test.tex
\documentclass{article}
\newenvironment{testenv}{\def\foobar{1}\document}{The End\enddocument}
\begin{testenv}
Test\foorbar Test
\end{testenv}
```

Note, the use case is a class which defines several environments following the same pattern, and using \AtBeginDocument/\AtEndDocument is not straight forward.

On Debian buster, this works as expected

```
% pdflatex test.tex 
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.19 (TeX Live 2019/dev/Debian) (preloaded format=pdflatex)
 restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
(./test.tex
LaTeX2e <2018-12-01>
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2018/09/03 v1.4i Standard LaTeX document class
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size10.clo)) (./test.aux)
[1{/var/lib/texmf/fonts/map/pdftex/updmap/pdftex.map}] (./test.aux) )</usr/shar
e/texlive/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmr10.pfb>
Output written on test.pdf (1 page, 10790 bytes).
Transcript written on test.log.
```

On Debian bullseye, I get

```
pdflatex test.tex 
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.21 (TeX Live 2020/Debian) (preloaded format=pdflatex)
 restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
(./test.tex
LaTeX2e <2020-10-01> patch level 4
L3 programming layer <2021-01-09> xparse <2020-03-03>
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2020/04/10 v1.4m Standard LaTeX document class
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size10.clo))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3backend/l3backend-pdftex.def)
(./test.aux)

! LaTeX Error: \begin{testenv} on input line 5 ended by \end{document}.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              
                                                  
l.7 \end{testenv}
                 
? 
[1{/var/lib/texmf/fonts/map/pdftex/updmap/pdftex.map}] (./test.aux) )
(\end occurred inside a group at level 1)

### semi simple group (level 1) entered at line 5 (\begingroup)
### bottom level</usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/c
mr10.pfb>
Output written on test.pdf (1 page, 10794 bytes).
Transcript written on test.log.
```

If it matters, the results are the same with lualatex or latex.

Comment: the version of tex you give in the title is unrelated to this, it is a latex feature and a documented change in the 2020 release

Comment: although this did not generate an error previously it puts a group around the entire document which increases the memory consumption of the document, latex has always ensured that uniquely the document enviornment does not form a group

Answer (score 8):

This is unrelated to the version of TeX, or the operating system, it is a documented change in `\document` which had some adjustments to accomodate the new hook system.

Declaring the outer environment that way would be inefficient even in earlier releases where it did not give an error as it would place a group around the document causing tex to save all values set during the document to restore at the end of the group.

A version of the definition that works without error and without introducing a group level is

```
\documentclass{article}
\let\testenv\document
\let\endtestenv\enddocument
\begin{testenv}
Test
\end{testenv}
```

---

With the extended example added later you can insert the additional code using the hook mechanism

```
\documentclass{article}
\AddToHook{begindocument/before}{\def\foorbar{1}}
\AddToHook{enddocument}{The End}
\let\testenv\document
\let\endtestenv\enddocument
\begin{testenv}
Test\foorbar Test
\end{testenv}
```

although best practice would be to just use the hooks and not rename `document` so

```
\documentclass{article}
\AddToHook{begindocument/before}{\def\foorbar{1}}
\AddToHook{enddocument}{The End}

\begin{document}
Test\foorbar Test
\end{document}
```

Of course adding such code without different packages trying to re-define `\document` and tripping over each other is the reason for adding these standard hooks. In general it has proved a very compatible change at the document level, and does not affect most packages, although as you found, sorry, it does impact code that was previously patching in to `\begin{document}` "by hand".

See `texdoc lthooks` for more detail on the hook mechanism.

https://texdoc.org/serve/lthooks/0

Comment: Thank you.  That solves the minimal example.  I'll edit the question with a more real example.

Comment: @George I updated the answer to match

Comment: Thanks. Is \AddToHook{begindocument/before} equivalent to \AtBeginDocument?

Comment: Thanks a lot. The remaining problem is to have a package defining several environments similar to testenv, but making different definitions.  Yes, it could be resolved by using a class option instead, I just have that little hope of not having to fix every document using the class.

Comment: @George no `\AtBeginDocument` is `\AddtoHook{begindocument}`   the /before one is more or less the end of the preamble (before the aux file is read) there is also begindocument/after which is right at the end after fonts etc set up so (unlike AtBeginDocument) it's safe to do typesetting

Comment: @George given that in general we try not to break stuff, if we do break stuff we will try to help work around things so if you want to extend the example more either here or as an issue at te hegithub we'll see what we can do. Basically if you have to update the class, that;s a "known proce for the change" but it would be good if you could do that without requiring document changes.

Comment: @George https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/59139683#59139683